# Calculation in grouped dataframe with date type index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like:

```
date_time       value
30.04.20 9:31   1
30.04.20 10:12  5
30.04.20 15:16  2
01.05.20 12:01  63
01.05.20 13:00  78
02.05.20 7:23   4
02.05.20 17:34  2
02.05.20 18:34  4
02.05.20 21:39  3458
03.05.20 9:34   77
03.05.20 14:54  4
03.05.20 16:54  7
04.05.20 15:24  35
```

I need to group records within a day and calculate the average over 3 days (day_before-today-next_day) period as follows (desired result):

```
    date    value
01.05.2020  3617
02.05.2020  3697
03.05.2020  3591
```

I wrote the beginning of the code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(...)
df['date'] = df['date_time'].dt.normalize()
df.groupby('date').sum()
```

The grouped dataframe here looks like:

```
date    value
30.04.2020  8
01.05.2020  141
02.05.2020  3468
03.05.2020  88
04.05.2020  35
```

But I can't go further because I don't understand how to get the desired result in a concise "pandas" way. Please give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have done your work, just add these lines of code to your current solution:

```
df_group = df.groupby('date').sum()
results = df_group.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3, center=True).sum()

print(results)
2020-04-30     NaN
2020-05-01  3617.0
2020-05-02  3697.0
2020-05-03  3591.0
2020-05-04     NaN

# retain only rows with values
print(results.dropna())
date              
2020-05-01  3617.0
2020-05-02  3697.0
2020-05-03  3591.0
```

Hope this helps!